# What data does Django 1.5 SplitDateTimeWidget send to form.clean()?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have the following form:

```
class TripForm(IntranetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TripForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('reason', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('departure_date'),
            Field('return_date'),
            Field(
                'date_and_time_of_first_appointment',
            ),
            Field(
                'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes',
            ),
            Field(
                'departure_location',
                template='travel/related_departure.html',
            ),
            Field(
                'destination',
                template='travel/related_destination.html',
            ),
            Field('mode_of_transport', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('seating_preference', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('special_requests', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            FormActions(
                Submit(
                    'save_changes',
                    'Save changes',
                    css_class = "btn-primary",
                ),
                Button(
                    'cancel',
                    'Cancel',
                    onclick = 'history.go(-1);'
                ),
            ),
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TripForm, self).clean()
        departure_date = cleaned_data.get("departure_date")
        return_date = cleaned_data.get("return_date")
        a1 = cleaned_data.get("date_and_time_of_first_appointment")
        af = cleaned_data.get("date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes")

        if departure_date < datetime.date.today():
            msg = u"Must be a date in the future."
            self._errors["departure_date"] = self.error_class([msg])

            del cleaned_data["departure_date"]

        if a1.date() < departure_date:
            msg = u"Must be after the departure date."
            self._errors["date_and_time_of_first_appointment"] = self.error_class([msg])

            del cleaned_data["date_and_time_of_first_appointment"]

        if return_date < departure_date:
            msg = u"Must be after the departure date."
            self._errors["return_date"] = self.error_class([msg])

            del cleaned_data["return_date"]

        if af < a1 or af.date() > return_date:
            msg = u"Must be after the first appointment and before the return date."
            self._errors["date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes"] = self.error_class([msg])

            del cleaned_data["date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes"]

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = (
            'reason',
            'departure_date',
            'return_date',
            'date_and_time_of_first_appointment',
            'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes',
            'departure_location',
            'destination',
            'mode_of_transport',
            'seating_preference',
            'special_requests',
        )
        widgets = {
            'date_and_time_of_first_appointment': SplitDateTimeWidget(),
            'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes': SplitDateTimeWidget(),
        }
```

Tests similar to the one below all work fine when I **don't** use the `SplitDateTimeWidget`.

```
def test_trip_form_with_good_data(self):
    form_data = {
        'reason': 'HE',
        'departure_date': timezone.datetime.today(),
        'return_date': timezone.datetime.today(),
        'date_and_time_of_first_appointment': timezone.now(),
        'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes': timezone.now(),
        'departure_location': 1,
        'destination': 1,
        'mode_of_transport': 'TR',
        'seating_preference': 'Near the front',
        'special_requests': 'Make it nice',
    }
    form = TripForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

But the tests no longer run when the `SplitDateTimeWidget` is being used for the `DateTime` fields. They throw errors rather than failing, specifically:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'
```

whenever the `a1` variable is accessed in my overridden form `clean` method.

I've looked at the relevant source code and couldn't see why using the `SelectDateTimeWidget` would necessitate different input at the command line or in tests, but clearly it does. How should my tests provide data in a way that the form `clean` method will be able to access?

EDIT:
Taking my cue from the rendered html I've also tried getting separate dates and times from fields like `date_and_time_of_first_appointment_0` and `date_and_time_of_first_appointment_1` and combining them before comparison in the `clean` method but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The rendered html was indeed telling me what to do but I put my solution in the wrong place.

Instead of looking for separate fields in the clean method, which is what I originally tried, you need to put them in your test data. Django will have combined them by the time the data is passed to `clean()`. My tests now look something like:

```
def test_trip_form_with_good_data(self):
    form_data = {
        'reason': 'HE',
        'departure_date': timezone.datetime.today(),
        'return_date': timezone.datetime.today(),
        'date_and_time_of_first_appointment_0': timezone.now().date(),
        'date_and_time_of_first_appointment_1': timezone.now().time(),
        'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes_0': timezone.now().date(),
        'date_and_time_final_appointment_finishes_1': timezone.now().time(),
        'departure_location': 1,
        'destination': 1,
        'mode_of_transport': 'TR',
        'seating_preference': 'Near the front',
        'special_requests': 'Make it nice',
    }
    form = TripForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

And everything passes again.